# setPropertyActionListeners to composite component

Tags: jsf, facelets, actionlistener, composite-component

I need to create composite component containing two h:commandLinks. And i want to pass f:setPropertyActionListeners from the client-code to be applied to both two commandLinks. Is this ever possible? I tried to use  cc:insertChildren, but appropriate setters are not being fired.

```
<my:operationLink action="#{cc.attrs.bean.myAction}">
 <f:setPropertyActionListener for="<!-- whats here? -->" value="#{cc.attrs.someAttrOne}" target="#{cc.attrs.bean.someAttrTargetOne}"/>
 <f:setPropertyActionListener for="<!-- whats here? -->" value="#{cc.attrs.someAttrTwo}" target="#{cc.attrs.bean.someAttrTargetTwo}"/>
```

and my component:

```
<cc:implementation>
<h:commandLink id="textLink" value="myTextLink"><ui:insert/></h:commandLink>
<h:commandLink id="imgLink"><h:graphicImage url="/images/my.gif"/><ui:insert/></h:commandLink>
```

i need to apply actionlisteners to both links ( into ui:insert)

Comment: * tried to use cc:insertChildren tag

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: added code to original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare a [`<cc:actionSource>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/composite/actionSource.html) in the composite interface with the "event name" in `name` (e.g. `actionEvent`, this is fully arbitrary to your choice) and the client IDs of those command links space separated in the `targets`.

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:actionSource name="actionEvent" targets="textLink imgLink" />
</cc:interface>
```

Then you can use in the client:

```
<f:setPropertyActionListener for="actionEvent" ... />
```

Don't forget to remove `<ui:insert>`. This is indeed definitely not the right way.

Comment: Great! Works as expected! Thanks a lot!